# converting FIX::DateTime to FIX::UTCTIMESTAMP

Tags: c++, quickfix

I am working on a C++ quickfix program where I obtain the current time using

```
ctm = FIX::DateTime::nowUtc() ;
```

I prefer to use the datetime format because I want to do some math to calculate an expiry time for an order.

the FIX::ExpireTime constructor seems to need a time in the utctimestamp class

Can anyone tell me how to convert a datetime class to a utctimestamp class ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that would do:

```
FIX::UtcTimeStamp timeStamp = FIX::UtcTimeStamp();
FIX::ExpireTime expire = FIX::ExpireTime(timeStamp.getTimeT());
```